# Changing the default Context of the Apiman Target Gateway URL

Tags: apiman

I have [Apiman](https://apiman.io) installed and found it very useful. However, I would like to change the context of the target URL generated for published APIs. It creates them under "/apiman-gateway" context. Would like to change this to more user-friendly.  Did not find any configuration out of the box to change this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also consider using the Vert.x Gateway distribution which is a bit easier to handle in this respect as it just binds to a port with no context/path prefix element.

Disclosure: I develop Apiman.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further digging in google, found this [suggestion from Jboss forum](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/apiman-user/2016-March/000595.html). This is not a configuration, but rebuild the default apigateway war and publish with a different context.